# How does BitConverter.ToInt32 work?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Here is a method -

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //
        // Create an array of four bytes.
        // ... Then convert it into an integer and unsigned integer.
        //
        byte[] array = new byte[4];
        array[0] = 1; // Lowest
        array[1] = 64;
        array[2] = 0;
        array[3] = 0; // Sign bit
        //
        // Use BitConverter to convert the bytes to an int and a uint.
        // ... The int and uint can have different values if the sign bit differs.
        //
        int result1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(array, 0); // Start at first index
        uint result2 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(array, 0); // First index
        Console.WriteLine(result1);
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output

16385
16385

I just want to know how this is happening?

Answer (score 16):

The docs for [`BitConverter.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx) actually have some pretty good examples. Assuming [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) returns true, `array[0]` is the least significant byte, as you've shown... although `array[3]` isn't just the sign bit, it's the most significant byte which *includes* the sign bit (as bit 7) but the rest of the bits are for magnitude.

So in your case, the least significant byte is 1, and the next byte is 64 - so the result is:

```
( 1 * (1 << 0) ) +    // Bottom 8 bits
(64 * (1 << 8) ) +    // Next 8 bits, i.e. multiply by 256
( 0 * (1 << 16)) +    // Next 8 bits, i.e. multiply by 65,536
( 0 * (1 << 24))      // Top 7 bits and sign bit, multiply by 16,777,216
```

which is 16385. If the sign bit were set, you'd need to consider the two cases differently, but in this case it's simple.

Comment: (tries to resist an urge to replace `+` with `|` ;p)

Comment: @Marc: Yeah, I wasn't sure... I felt that if the OP is *asking* about this, they're probably more comfortable with +.

Answer (score 4):

It converts like it was a number in base 256. So in your case : 1+64*256 = 16385

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the .Net 4.0 Framework [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), `BitConverter` does work how [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993840/how-does-bitconverter-toint32-work/7993914#7993914) said, though it uses pointers (`unsafe` code) to work with the array.

However, if the second argument (i.e., `startindex`) is divisible by 4 (as is the case in your example), the framework takes a shortcut.  It takes a `byte` pointer to the `value[startindex]`, casts it to an `int` pointer, then dereferences it.  This trick works regardless of whether `IsLittleEndian` is true.

From a high level, this basically just means the code is pointing at 4 bytes in the `byte` array and categorically declaring, "the chunk of memory over there is an `int`!" (and then returning a copy of it).  This makes perfect sense when you take into account that under the hood, an `int` *is* just a chunk of memory.

Below is the source code of the framework `ToUint32` method:

```
return (uint)ToInt32(value, startIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

> array[0] = 1; // Lowest       // 0x01
>  array[1] = 64;         //
>   0x40
>  array[2] = 0;         // 0x00
>  array[3] = 0; // Sign bit 
>   0x00

If you combine each hex value **0x00004001**

The MSDN documentatin explains everything

Answer (score 0):

You can look for yourself - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,e8230d40857425ba

If the data is word-aligned, it will simply cast the memory pointer to an int32.

```
return *((int *) pbyte);
```

Otherwise, it uses bitwise logic from the byte memory pointer values.

Answer (score -1):

For those of you who are having trouble with Little Endien and Big Endien.  I use the following wrapper functions to take care of it.

```
    public static Int16 ToInt16(byte[] data, int offset)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? data.Skip(offset).Take(2).Reverse().ToArray() : data, 0);
        }
        return BitConverter.ToInt16(data, offset);
    }

    public static Int32 ToInt32(byte[] data, int offset)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? data.Skip(offset).Take(4).Reverse().ToArray() : data, 0);
        }
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, offset);
    }

    public static Int64 ToInt64(byte[] data, int offset)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt64(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? data.Skip(offset).Take(8).Reverse().ToArray() : data, 0);
        }
        return BitConverter.ToInt64(data, offset);
    }
```

Comment: BitConverter already takes architecture Endianness into account.  If you do want to provide a `ToIntxx` function that accepts an Endianness argument independent of the current architecture, my recommendation would be to replace `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` with `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == isLittleEndian`, where `isLittleEndian` is an argument passed to the wrapper function.  Also, I find it really dirty that you are checking `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` in both your if statement and in the ternary operator.  Either use an if statement or a ternary operator but not both.

Comment: If your concern was some sort of race condition within `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`, your concern is misplaced.  Firstly, your solution doesn't resolve such a race condition (though it does narrow it).  Secondly, `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` indicates architecture Endianness.  The value of `IsLittleEndian` is set at compile time of the framework.